# How to prevent loops in laravel global variable

Tags: laravel

I've created file `GlobalVariable.php` inside `app\Composers`

```
public function compose($view)
{
    $categories = \App\Models\Category::all();
    $view->with('globCategory', $categories);
}
```

then register to `AppServiceProvider` the code `view()->composer('*', GlobalVariable::class);`

I use global `$globCategory` for creating dynamic navbar

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0 flex-column flex-lg-row">
    @foreach ($globCategory as $item)
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{ route('deal.category', ['category' => $item->slug]) }}" class="nav-link">{{$item->name}}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

the only problem here when I see laravel debuggar it show repetition of categories query.

here is the result

[image]

How to avoid this looping query? is there correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're registering your view composer (using `'*'` instead of a particular view name), it's going to call the `compose` method for every single rendered view + subview.

What you can do is instead of this:

```
view()->composer('*', GlobalVariable::class);
```

Have this:

```
\View::share('globCategory', \App\Models\Category::all());
```

This will globally share your categories (within views), and run the query only once.

Comment: Thank you. i didn't notice laravel documentation mention that view composer will be executed each time view is being rendered . Thanks mate :)

Comment: They will be executed for every view they're called for - using `*` means that view composer will be executed for -every- view. If you had `view()->composer('someList', GlobalVariable::class);` then it it would have been executely only for `someList` view.

Answer (score 0):

View composers, as described from the laravel documentation, bind data to a view every time it is rendered. They clean our code by getting fetching data once and passing it to the view.

While it is possible to get the data in every controller method and pass it to the single view, this approach may be undesirable.

Replace the `view name` with an `asterisk wildcard`.